# gitlab-runner failing to run the test opening of a gui frame on windows 7

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I am new member of the group with limited development knowledge. we are developing a package [scikit-surgeryoverlay](https://weisslab.cs.ucl.ac.uk/WEISS/SoftwareRepositories/SNAPPY/scikit-surgeryoverlay). We have gitlab runners which are running the test code. The tests related to graphical window rendering are passing on Linux and Mac runners but not on window runner. The tests I am referring are in scikit-surgeryoverlay/tests directory in the referenced repo.

Long story short, when we run the tests manually from cmd after login to windows machine the tests pass. However, when we commit the code and the gitlab-runner gets the code on the window machine the tests fail.

We also came to know about about windows 7 [fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063731/is-there-any-way-to-start-a-gui-application-from-a-windows-service-on-windows-7) about running GUI application.

The error we get are

`tests/vtk/test_vtk_overlay_window.py::test_vtk_render_window_settings ERROR: InvocationError for command 'C:\\Gitlab-Runner\\builds\\ee0f7a3f\\0\\WEISS\\SoftwareRepositories\\SNAPPY\\scikit-surgeryoverlay\\.tox\\py36\\Scripts\\coverage.EXE run -a --source ./sksurgeryoverlay -m pytest -v -s ./tests/' (exited with code 3221225477)`

I would like to know if it is gitlab-runner limitation or windows limitation and something could be done to pass the tests using gitlab-runner.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason is that windows do not easily allow to run gui application when user is not logged in. So You can keep the user logged in and lock the screen. Now you can run the gui tests as that user and it will pass.